# How use html geo meta tags on travel agency web-site?

Tags: meta-tags, geolocation, geotagging

Our travel agency is in Moscow, and sells tours in other regions. We use geo meta tags in our site because they are [used by Bing](https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/020870.html).

According to [the IETF geo tagging draft specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daviel-html-geo-tag-08#section-7), hotel pages should contain meta geo-tags of the region in which the hotel is located.

> The geographic position given is associated with the resource described by the HTML document, not with the physical location of the document [RFC1876], or the location of the company responsible for publishing or hosting the document.

```
<meta name="geo.placename" content="..." />
<meta name="geo.position" content="..." />
<meta name="geo.region" content="..." />
<meta name="ICBM" content="...." />
```

But the agency’s clients are located in Moscow and in other regions other than where the hotel is located. If the pages of hotels begin to be actively displayed in search engines in the regions where the hotels are located, then this is not the result that is needed.
Put on the pages of hotels geo-tags of the location of the travel agency and more actively show the pages of hotels in search engines for customers from the region in which the travel agency is located?
Or do not put geo tags on hotel pages at all?

In my opinion, this is not suitable for the tourism industry, because the objects located on HTML pages need to be promoted in a different region.